# Can you give your account to someone else?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've made some progress and want to give my account to a friend's iCloud account, so I can continue playing on their iPad instead of my phone. Is this possible?

Note that we are using different iTunes accounts on these devices.

Answer (score 2):

**Using built-in options for saves, no.**

**Using 3rd party software, yes.**

You can copy the save file off your iOS device and put it on another.

> 1. Make sure you're 100% up-to-date on Fallout Shelter, your device, iTunes, all that good stuff. I know, iTunes is a pain in the ass to update, but it does need to be current.
> 2. With iTunes open, plug in your device and manually back it up (I used an iPad Air, but I'm sure this would work with iPhones or iPods.)
> 3. With your backup completed, close iTunes and download the free trial of iBackupBot for Windows (I promise it's legit, and this isn't /r/hailcorporate.) You can get it [here](http://www.icopybot.com/download.htm). Do not unplug your device.
> 4. Once that's done installing, open the program and look for "Fallout Shelter." For me, it was Backup > User App Files > Fallout Shelter > Documents. There you'll find your vault(s): Vault1.sav, Vault2.sav, Vault3.sav.
> 5. Click on that mamajama, and "Export" to a safe location. **ALWAYS MAKE BACKUPS BEFORE DOING ANYTHING!**
> 6. Edit it using the resources in this post. Once happy with a vault of a billion MIRVs, press the "Import" button back in iBackupBot to import it. Pretty self-explanatory, but hey.
> 7. But wait! You've edited the backup .sav of the backup and done a simple switcheroo, but it needs committed to your device. For this, press "Restore;" it won't take too long to finish this step. It was probably about a minute for me.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3jx6lg/how_to_edit_your_83_ios_saves_without_jailbreak/)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot accomplish this. It is possible to transfer a vault to and from another device with the same iCloud account, but not between iCloud accounts.

See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/3gvrga/fallout_shelter_how_to_backup_or_transfer_your/):

> This should be pretty easy now with iCloud saving. On your old device, make sure you tick off "iCloud" on the vault list. Then, tick off "iCloud" on the same slot on your new device. Your game should be loaded.
>
> FYI mac users can now access their sav game files from Terminal:

```
cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents
open iCloud~com~bethsoft~falloutshelter
```

As these steps require the devices to be on the same iCloud account, you cannot transfer to a friend's device with a separate account.